# Trouble-shooting a basic test with React and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have setup a basic test with React and Jest. It seems to be failing for some reason.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
// import App from '../src/client/app.jsx';

const App = (props) => (
  <div>Hello world</div>
);

it('App renders hello world', () => {
  const app1 = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<App />);
  const appNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(app1);
  console.log(app1, appNode);
  expect(appNode.textContent).toEqual('Hello world');
});
```

Both app1 and appNode are null when printed to the console. Any help?

Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TestUtils and React Stateless Components](http://t4d.io/jest-testutils-and-react-stateless-components/):

> the suggested solution is to wrap the component inside of another
>   component such as a DIV.

```
const app1 = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<div><App /></div>); // this should work
```